# Does create index on a column always sort that column in background?

Tags: sql, database, sorting, search, indexing

I used SQL a lot but I never cared about how it works on a deeper level. Recently I've been doing some research about **keys** and **indexes**. I have some questions about how exactly the **index** work.

As I understand, when I create an index on a column, the **index stores a copy of the indexed column along with a reference to the corresponding table row** in **sorted order**.

For example, if I have a table like below

```
Id Name
2  B
1  A
3  C
```

Then if I create an index on the **"Name"** column the index "table" will be something like

```
Name Pointer
A    Row2
B    Row1
C    Row3
```

With sorted order like this, it will be faster when searching for "Name" since you can apply an algorithm like binary search, which time-complexity can be O(logn) instead of O(n)

Does it mean that creating an index on a column **always sorts that column in the background** and **it's the only way**? Because if it's not sorted, then the time complexity when searching for a specific value is still like scanning the whole table, which makes no change.

Comment: It may depend on what flavor of SQL you are using.  You should tag which.

Comment: Might be worth reading up on some of the ways indexes are stored, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @TimothyG. I mainly use Mysql. But do indexes work differently for different kinds of SQL engines? Because when I search something like "what is index in database" on Google, most of the articles I read never mention a specific SQL engine, they never said something like "in MySQL index work like this, in Postgres SQL index work like that,..."

Comment: Indexes don’t sort columns in the actual table, if that’s what you are asking? Instead they are a sorted pointer to the row that contains the value in the index. So when you run a query that uses the index it queries the sorted index (fast) and gets the rows that contain the indexed values; getting those actual rows is then fast - it’s not doing a table scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "I mainly use Mysql" -- Even for that case, it depends.

- Older versions of MySQL and MariaDB would rebuild the table including the new index and any previous indexes.
- Newer versions do the `CREATE INDEX` in the background and eventually allow queries to use it.

The `PRIMARY KEY` in MySQL (and a "clustered" index in many other brands) will order the data by that key.  A "secondary" index, itself, is sorted by the key in a "B+Tree", but has to reach over into the data's B+Tree to get the rest of the columns.

For a many-to-many-mapping table it is a good idea to build two indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_bars (
    foo_id ...,
    bar_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(foo_id, bar_id),
    INDEX(bar_id, foo_id) )
```

That way, you get two fully sorted lookup BTrees.

"binary search" -- Read about BTrees; they are better than binary search when the data can be so big that it needs to be fetched from disk.

"reference to the corresponding table row" -- In InnoDB, the reference is a copy of the `PRIMARY KEY`, hence a second BTree lookup.  In MyISAM it is an address into the `.MYD` file, a single file seek. In some other vendors, it is a "row number".

A "Columnstore" table is a radically different animal.  It involves a 2-level lookup and uncompression.

A "Fulltext" index is essentially an inverted lookup of 'word' -> 'row.

A "Spatial" index is an "R-Tree".  Ordinary indexes are 1-dimensional; Spatial gives you a 2-dimensional index.

- `WHERE x = 2` -- A "point query" -- BTree lookup
- `WHERE x BETWEEN 4 AND 44` -- First a Btree lookup, then use the `+` in B+Tree to do a "range scan"
- Otherwise, use a "table scan" (or "index scan") -- Look at every row.

Hope this helps; sorry that I don't have details for Postgres, etc.